# Joining string of a columns over several index while keeping other colums

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example data set:

```
>>> df1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["Alice", "Marie", "Smith", "Mallory", "Bob", "Doe"],
    "City": ["Seattle", None, None, "Portland", None, None],
    "Age": [24, None, None, 26, None, None],
    "Group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})

>>> df1
    Age      City  Group     Name
0  24.0   Seattle      1    Alice
1   NaN      None      1    Marie
2   NaN      None      1    Smith
3  26.0  Portland      2  Mallory
4   NaN      None      2      Bob
5   NaN      None      2      Doe
```

I would like to merge the Name column for all index of the same group while keeping the City and the Age wanting someting like:

```
>>> df1_summarised
    Age      City  Group     Name
0  24.0   Seattle      1    Alice Marie Smith
1  26.0  Portland      2    Mallory Bob Doe
```

I know those 2 columns (Age, City) will be NaN/None after the first index of a given group from the structure of my starting data.

I have tried the following:

```
>>> print(df1.groupby('Group')['Name'].apply(' '.join))
Group
1    Alice Marie Smith
2      Mallory Bob Doe
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

But I would like to keep the Age and City columns...

Comment: Please pay attention at [piRSquared's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40090538/5741205) - it's 3 times faster compared to mine. I would choose his answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `dropna` and `assign` with `groupby`

[docs to assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df1.dropna(subset=['Age', 'City']) \
   .assign(Name=df1.groupby('Group').Name.apply(' '.join).values)
```

[image]

---

***timing***
per request

[image]

---

***update***
use `groupby` and `agg`
I thought of this and it feels far more satisfying

```
df1.groupby('Group').agg(dict(Age='first', City='first', Name=' '.join))
```

to get the exact output

```
df1.groupby('Group').agg(dict(Age='first', City='first', Name=' '.join)) \
   .reset_index().reindex_axis(df1.columns, 1)
```

Comment: I think your solution should be faster. Could you add some timing?

Comment: @MaxU that `reset_index` I put at the end adds about a millisecond.  In other words, it wasn't what makes the difference.  However, OP didn't say they cared and thing your answer is more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for timing! I knew your solution is faster... ;)

Comment: Could you give a reference to the documentation of the assign function? I could not determine if it comes from pandas, numpy or base python and what it does exactly.

Comment: @piRSquared, wow, that's really smart! It's a pity - i can't upvote it for the second time :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
In [29]: df1.groupby('Group').ffill().groupby(['Group','Age','City']).Name.apply(' '.join)
Out[29]:
Group  Age   City
1      24.0  Seattle     Alice Marie Smith
2      26.0  Portland      Mallory Bob Doe
Name: Name, dtype: object
```